# disable vibration alert selectively on iMessages

Tags: ios, iphone, messages

When an iMessage comes in, I want to disable vibration. I just want the tone play. But when a call comes in, I want both vibration AND tone play simultaneously. Is there a way I can set that up on my iPhone (iOS 5.1). The reason I want no vibration with iMessages/SMS is to conserver battery. Let me know if vibration does not sap away my battery in which case I would not worry about this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, don't think this is possible in any current version of iOS.

You could try setting up a custom vibration pattern that was close to non-existant:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/242238/how_to_use_custom_vibrations_in_ios_5.html

Comment: That's a good improvisation - setting up "vibration pattern that was close to non-existant." If nothing, I guess, that's the next best thing. Thanks Keefer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry there's not a better solution.